# Phonegap send image with Ajax results in [Object ArrayBuffer] instead of binary

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a function to get a photo and get the FILE_URI. Which works:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (data) {

    if (data === false) {
        // Error, or cancel
    } else {
        var fio = new FileIO();
        fio.getFile(data, function(result){
            _this.photo = result;
        }, function(){ });
        _this.templateManager.holder.find("#profielFoto").css("background-image", "url(" + data + ")").addClass("picture");
    }

}, function(){  
}, {
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation: true,
    targetWidth : 200,
    targetHeight: 200
});
```

Now next, the result I get from fio.getFile is the result of:

```
FileIO.prototype.getFile = function(filename, cb, error){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(filename, function(fileEntry) { 
        fileEntry.file( function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                cb(evt.target.result);
            };
            //reader.onerror = error;
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }, error);
    }, error);
};
```

So the `_this.photo` is an ArrayBuffer. Now I wan't to send this with an ajax post. This is possible but I can't get it to work. The data in the database is [Object ArrayBuffer], but I don't do a tostring or anything.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("photo", this.photo);
data.append("firstname", $("input[name=firstname]").val());
data.append("insertion", $("input[name=insertion]").val());
data.append("lastname", $("input[name=lastname]").val());
data.append("emailaddress", $("input[name=emailaddress]").val());
data.append("passwordhash", $("input[name=passwordhash]").val());

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', PostURL, true);
xhr.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        alert("OK"); 
    } else {
      alert("ERROR");
    }
  };
xhr.send(data);
```

**Question: How is it possible this posts a [Object ArrayBuffer] instead of my binary data?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the FileTransfer plugin instead. http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer